# New to Coq: How to compile .vo files and run command line?

Tags: math, coq

I'm new to working with Coq, and I'm progressing through the first volume of the Software Foundations book, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to compile the Basics.v file for the second chapter on induction.

I've seen things floating around about using the Coqc command on the command line, but I don't know how to access the terminal, or at least the windows terminal doesn't recognize the command. If anyone could walk me through this it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: What is your operating system? Can you run `make`?

Comment: You need provide more informations about your environment

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using CoqIDE, there is a menu item "Compile/Compile buffer", which creates a .vo file for the currently loaded .v file. For a few files and early stages of learning, this might be the easiest way.

Then SF likely comes with a make file which you can just run with make. You didn't say what OS your are using - on Linux and Mac this should be trivial, on Windows it depends on how you did install Coq. The Windows installer doesn't come with make, but if you used the Coq Platform scripts to setup Coq on Windows, everything is there.

Otherwise it might get a bit complicated - you need to pass the right options to coqc (which CoqIDE and make do automatically for you).